# android html5, how to get a photo from the Gallery app and put it into a canvas

Tags: html

I need the following:

- I have a html5 application on android
- When the user clicks on the button "Select image", android shows the default Gallery app (or any other app of the user), and the user selects one of this photos
- android returns back to my html5 page, passing the userImage, and the html5 page puts the image into a canvas (instead of uploading the photo to a server through a web form):

  var ctx = document.getElementById("myCanvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(userImage, 0, 0);

how to do this with HTML5 getUserMedia API?

Comment: ok. however, using `<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>` will upload the photo to the webserver through the form, isn't it? I need to put the photo in a html canvas, using a static html page, without sending data to the webserver.

Comment: great! I see a simple demo here: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/file-click-demo.html , with documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/samples/domref/file-click-demo.htmlhttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images
please write this down as an answer so that I can award it to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [getUserMedia API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia) is a capture API.
Which means it will access to hardware media (camera, microphone). You won't be able to access saved images (e.g in Gallery app) through this API.
Maybe you'll be more interested in `<input type="file" accept="image/*"/>` way to get an image from this kind of app.
The Image selected by the user will be stored in browser cache, accessible through `youInputElement.files`.

To draw it on a canvas, you'll have to pass it to a new Image(), thanks to [URL.createObjectUrL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) or [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader);

As you noticed, there is [an example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images).